# How to Print 7 Days of week by taking user input?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

The Issue is when first time I run my Program and enter 5 than program will return **Friday** and after this press **y** to restart the operation without closing the console and enter **9** the program will return the default error message and will also return **Friday** which is a bad error in my code and I cannot Identify what makes it wrong.
The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

enum Dayofweek {monday = 1 , tuesday = 2, wednesday = 3, thursday = 4, friday = 5, saturday = 6, sunday = 7};
string Day (Dayofweek);
int main()
{
    int i;
    char resTart;
    Dayofweek d = monday;
    do
    {
        cin.clear();
        system ("cls");
        cout << "Enter the day of a week:[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7]:  ";
        while (!(cin >> i))
        {
        //system ("cls");
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        system ("cls");
        cout << "Invalid Input detected, Only numbers are allowed. 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6 ,7. Try Again." << '\n';
        cout << "Enter the day of a week: ";
        }
    cout << Day (Dayofweek (i)) << '\n';
    do
    {

        cin.clear();
        cout << "Do you want to Continue [Y/n]" << '\n';
        cin >> resTart;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        system ("cls");
    }while (resTart != 'Y' && resTart != 'y' && resTart != 'N' && resTart != 'n' );

    }while (resTart == 'Y' || resTart == 'y');

}
string Day (Dayofweek d)
{
    switch (d)
    {
        case 1:
        return "Monday";
        case 2:
        return "Tuesday";
        case 3:
        return "Wednesday";
        case 4:
        return "Thursday";
        case 5:
        return "Friday";
        case 6:
        return "Saturday";
        case 7:
        return "Sunday";
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input detected, Only numbers are allowed in limit to 7 days of week, Try Again." << '\n';
    }
}
```

OutPut in Console:
Enter the day of a week:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG0u7.png) [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7]:  9
Invalid Input detected, Only numbers are allowed. 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6 ,7. Try Again.
Friday
Do you want to Continue [Y/n]

[image]

Comment: Please, please, please, post text as *text*, not images. I don't get this obsession with screenshots when copy and pasting the text is actually easier and makes it searchable and accessible to people using screen readers. Why an image? It's less useful for the audience and in most cases more work to create. I *don't* get it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The question contain the full source of my code in text, and image is an extra option.

Comment: But, *everything* in that image could have been posted as text and that would have been better than posting the image. So *why* an image?

Comment: @JesperJuhl everything is posted as text, check it again )

Comment: No. It's not. What is in that console window is not in the question as text.  But never mind...

Comment: @JesperJuhl In the console window is the output of my code and I can post it if it is very important, The question is Updated )

Comment: I didn't make a statement on whether it was important or not. My point was simply that text should *always* be preferred over images since text is far superior unless you are trying to show some graphical effect. And, I also just wondered *why* posting screenshots is so common since it's *easier* to just cut'n'paste the text rather than create and upload a screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213256/discussion-between-arnold-baba-and-jesper-juhl).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Day` function is supposed to return a `string`. However, you are not returning a `string` in the `default` case of the switch statement, which invokes undefined behaviour (in your case, the function returned "Friday", but *anything* can happen).

You need to return *something* for the program to be well-defined:

```
string Day (Dayofweek d)
{
    switch (d)
    {
        case 1:
        return "Monday";
        // etc ...  
        case 7:
        return "Sunday";
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input detected, Only numbers are allowed in limit to 7 days of week, Try Again." << '\n';
        return "not a day";
    }
}
```

I strongly recommend turning on all warnings in your compiler (e.g. with `gcc`, and `clang`, you can pass `-Wall` as a compilation flag). The compiler will let you know that you are doing something that might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much the issue is resolved by your answer) I can accept your answer in 3 minutes.

Comment: No worries. Please see the additional comment about turning on warnings.

Comment: Ok I will do it for sure)

Answer (score 3):

Just return a null string when the execution end's with an invalid value.

```
string Day (Dayofweek d)
{
    string null;
    switch (d)
    {
        case 1:
        return "Monday";
        case 2:
        return "Tuesday";
        case 3:
        return "Wednesday";
        case 4:
        return "Thursday";
        case 5:
        return "Friday";
        case 6:
        return "Saturday";
        case 7:
        return "Sunday";
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input detected, Only numbers are allowed. 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6 ,7. Try Again." << '\n';
        return string (null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's also working ) and maybe just:  return  (null);